# h2o and setting destination frame from python

Tags: python, parquet, h2o

We use python to talk to single instance h2o (latest version 3.22.1.1).

Sometimes we get this error:

```
DistributedException from /10.192.21.17:54321: 'class water.fvec.Frame s3a://BUCKET_NAME/part-00001-0cd59acc-d03f-4af6-8227-e58bf7ad9562-c000.snappy.parquet is already in use.  Unable to use it now.  Consider using a different destination name.', caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class water.fvec.Frame s3a://BUCKET_NAME/part-00001-0cd59acc-d03f-4af6-8227-e58bf7ad9562-c000.snappy.parquet is already in use.  Unable to use it now.  Consider using a different destination name.
    at water.MRTask.getResult(MRTask.java:478)
    at water.MRTask.getResult(MRTask.java:486)
    at water.MRTask.doAll(MRTask.java:402)
```

We tried to pass our random destination_frame like this:

```
h2o.import_file(
                path=data_path,
                destination_frame='frame_{}'.format(str(uuid.uuid4())))
```

but it looks like destination_frame parameters is not used by H2O even though we see it present in the logs:

```
POST /3/Parse, parms: {number_columns=94, source_frames=["s3a://BUCKET_NAME/part-00000-0cd59acc-d03f-4af6-8227-e58bf7ad9562-c000.snappy.parquet"], column_types=["UUID","Numeric","Numeric","Numeric","Numeric","Numeric","Numeric","Enum","Enum","Time","Numeric","Enum","Enum","Time","Time","Numeric","Enum","Enum","Numeric","Enum","Numeric","Numeric","Numeric","Enum","Enum","Enum","Enum","Enum","Numeric","Enum","Enum","Numeric","Enum","Numeric","Numeric","Numeric","Numeric","Numeric","Numeric","Numeric","Numeric","Time","Numeric","Enum","Enum","Time","Numeric","Numeric","Enum","Enum","Enum","Enum","Enum","Numeric","Enum","Numeric","Enum","Numeric","Enum","Numeric","Enum","Numeric","Enum","Numeric","Numeric","Numeric","Numeric","UUID","Time","Numeric","Numeric","Enum","Numeric","Numeric","Numeric","Enum","Numeric","Numeric","Enum","Enum","Numeric","UUID","Numeric","Numeric","Numeric","Numeric","Numeric","Numeric","Numeric","Numeric","Enum","Numeric","Numeric","Numeric"], single_quotes=True, parse_type=PARQUET, destination_frame=frame_19d32a0b-812f-4179-ba83-c3e1afe1d84f, column_names=[
"ALL_COLUMN_NAMES_HERE"], delete_on_done=True, check_header=1, separator=124, blocking=False, chunk_size=77450}
```

Comment: please post the code that generated the first error (which is saying that your S3 bucket is already in use). Please restart h2o and do a fresh test of your code, then run `h2o.ls()` and see whether or not it lists your destinations frame and update your question with the output. Thanks!

Comment: Well this is the code that caused issue `h2o.import_file(path=data_path, destination_frame='frame_{}'.format(str(uuid.uuid4())))` - sometimes we have to load same s3 files in parallel to same h2o nodes to build different models.. and my understanding was that if we use unique destination_frames (like uuid) it should be possible to do it?